# Lighttpd and buffering of POST uploads to CGI on embedded device

Tags: post, nginx, embedded, cgi, lighttpd

I'm using lighttpd on an embedded device with relatively low amounts of RAM and flash storage, and I'm running into the issue with Lighttpd where it's buffering to disk(or RAM) the entire file upload and the system is running out of space. When using apache, it will essentially stream through the data directly to the CGI program, which is what I need.
From my research, I haven't been able to find any way to configure lighttpd (or nginx) in order so that it will not buffer the entire file upload, but rather pass it directly or stream it to the CGI program which will consume it.
The application is a system upgrade which will be written directly to a certain area of flash by the CGI program, but I simply don't have the space for any type of buffering/caching which seems to be required by the lightweight web servers I have looked at.

Does anyone know of a way to avoid this buffering with lighttpd/nginx or other lightweight web server ?

Comment: seems there is no way to do this with lighttpd

Answer (score 1):

The [Nginx Upload Module](https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-upload-module) was written to handle these types of situations but it appears abandoned by the author and apparently does not work with Nginx 1.3.9+

The [Nginx Big Upload Module](https://github.com/pgaertig/nginx-big-upload) is an extension to the [Nginx Lua Module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule) to handle this.

If you prefer to do things yourself, you can try the [Lua Resty Upload](https://github.com/agentzh/lua-resty-upload) extension to the [Nginx Lua Module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule) written by the author of the Lua Module himself.

Answer (score 0):

Since lighttpd 1.4.40 (released July 2016) `server.stream-request-body = 2`

See lighttpd [server.stream-request-body](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Server_stream-request-bodyDetails) doc

(old question, but it came up at the top of a search, so I am updating with an answer)